# C++ Async Tasks. Include "Future" trouble

Tags: c++, asynchronous, header, include, future

My compiler doesn't find `#include <future>` when I need to execute an Async Task. How can I include it properly? Can I download the headers and make a reference to them?

Comment: Does your compiler have `C++11` or `C++14` support? Is it possible to switch the support on using some setting or option?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042671/c11-standard-library-is-not-found-xcode5-llvm5-1-libc

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2005 Compiler.

Comment: It's unlikely you'll solve this by downloading headers. The C++ standard library is normally very tightly coupled to a particular compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::future` is C++11 onwards.

Visual Studio 2005 does not support the C++11 and C++14 standards, so no.

(It barely gets the `for` scoping correct!)

Consider upgrading your toolchain, but note that VC2012 only partially supports C++11 features. You could try `boost` (www.boost.org). It contains material that's often accepted into future standards, so may well contain a `future` that can be compiled with VC2005.

Comment: I'll check it thanks. Btw, is there a way I can execute an async task using VS2005 compiler? I can't upgrade it.